# Foreign film about a dystopian future where people age 30 or over can get "regenerations"

Tags: story-identification, movie, dystopia, regeneration

It was a foreign film about a dystopian future where at age 30 people can start getting "regenerations". You can literally go into a place like a dairy and get regenerated; it's that easy. The guy went and got his bi-yearly regeneration, hungover, at a random shitty place after drinking all night.  And so, because of this, people just keep on living and at this time there's lots of people that are over a hundred years old.

Because life gets boring and dull, old rich people attend "art shows" where a person under the age of 30 is put into a machine and rapidly aged until they die right in front of the audience and everyone just watches. The movie is about the condition of young people and also what problems future developments in health and increasing our life span could cause- lack of purpose, boredom, etc.

In this movie, people have several professions. In their possibly 150-year life span, they may have been a doctor, then an engineer, then an artist. In the movie, one of the women, Asian, was currently an opera singer.

Comment: Welcome Nat. Can you remember what language it was in, when it might have been made approximately? Any famous faces that you recall, any and all details might help. (Though it sounds familiar, but I've not seen it)

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Kind of an anti [Logan's Run](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074812).

Comment: Also "foreign" film depends on where you are. If you're living in the UK, Hollywood is "foreign" ...

Answer (score 11):

You may be thinking of ***[Ad Vitam](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8548830/)*** (2018).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_Vitam):

> *Ad Vitam* is a 2018 French-language TV series starring Yvan Attal, Garance Marillier and Niels Schneider. **The plot is set in a world where a highly effective medical treatment for aging called "Regeneration" has been discovered.** A cop, Darius Asram (Yvan Attal), and a rebellious young woman, Christa Novak (Garance Marillier), are investigating the suicides of seven teenagers.
>
> It was released on November 8, 2018, on Arte, and internationally on Netflix on June 21, 2019 but removed in September 2022.

From a [review](https://www.nextflicks.tv/review/ad-vitam/):

> Ad Vitam is a French production that intertwines a social exploration of indefinitely prolonged life through ‘regeneration’, and investigation of a spate of youth suicides. **Through medical breakthroughs involving jellyfish DNA, the ability to regenerate (and stop the aging process entirely) is now common. Adults seem to be able to keep on going: episode one features a 169th birthday celebration.** In that respect, it's quite similar to Altered Carbon.
>
> **But the process isn’t compatible for everyone, and can’t begin until at minimum the age of 30. Therefore the legal age of ‘adulthood’ has been moved up from 18 to 30, leaving behind a disaffected youth that is condescended to by a society made up of an increasing number of centenarians.** As a think piece, this set up is full of rich potential.

The series begins with a news report about a Japanese woman celebrating her 169th birthday, making her the oldest human ever.

We then see one of the two protagonists, a world-weary detective, drinking in a bar late at night, and subsequently walking into a shop to undergo a regeneration, which involves lying down in a liquid-filled enclosure with breathing apparatus on and being subjected to bursts of radiation.

The process doesn't work on under-thirties, though, due to some difference in their cell structure. In fact, it can have the opposite effect, causing them to age more rapidly, and there's a scene where a group of old (but relatively young-looking) people in a museum gather around to enjoy the ghoulish spectacle of a (genuinely) young man being rapidly aged to death by this technology.

People in this society also undergo vocational retraining every so often, so they can move from one profession to another and effectively build a new life for themselves when the previous one gets stale, although I couldn't find any reference to anyone being (or having been) an opera singer.

Comment: For what it's worth, if anyone is intrigued by this series, I recommend giving it a watch. It's well-shot and acted, with a nice soundtrack.